# What is System.Void?

Tags: c#, .net, void

*I know that methods declared with `void` does not return anything.*

But it seems that in C#, `void` is more than just a keyword, but a real type.
`void` is an alias for `System.Void`, like `int` that is for `System.Int32`.

**Why am I not allowed to use that type?** *It does not make any sense, but these are just some thoughts about the logic.*

Neither

```
var nothing = new System.Void();
```

*(which says I should use `void` (Not an alias?))*
nor

```
var nothing = new void();
```

compiles.

It is also not possible to use something like that:

```
void GiveMeNothing() { }
void GiveMeNothingAgain()
{
    return GiveMeNothing();
}
```

**So what's the point with `System.Void`?**

Comment: hm,- `void GiveMeNothing() { }` works good in Mono.NET 3.5...

Comment: @0x69 But can you return the `void` of `GiveMeNothing` in an other `void`-returning method?

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote [an excellent article about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/29/the-void-is-invariant.aspx) a while back on his blog.

Comment: `void` is just an indicator that function returns nothing at all.

Comment: `IEnumerable<System.Void>` 

It's just a bunch of nothing

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/14/null-is-not-empty/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.void):

> The `Void` structure is used in the
> `System.Reflection` namespace, but is
> rarely useful in a typical
> application. The `Void` structure has no
> members other than the ones all types
> inherit from the `Object` class.

There's no reason really to use it in code.

Also:

```
var nothing = new void();
```

This doesn't compile for me. What do you mean when saying it "works"?

**Update:**

A method `void Foo()` does not return anything. `System.Void` is there so that if you ask (through Reflection) "what is the type of the return value of that method?", you can get the answer `typeof(System.Void)`. There is no technical reason it could not return `null` instead, but that would introduce a special case in the Reflection API, and special cases are to be avoided if possible.

Finally, it is not legal for a program to contain the expression `typeof(System.Void)`. However, that is a *compiler-enforced* restriction, not a CLR one. Indeed, if you try the allowed `typeof(void)` and look at its value in the debugger, you will see it is the same value it would be if `typeof(System.Void)` were legal.

Comment: so the developers did not thought through and even if they say me: _Your method returns a System.Void struct, you can not use it_? And for what is it used in `Reflection`?

Comment: @ordag: Your method does not return *anything*. `System.Void` is there so that if you ask "what is the type of the return value of `void Foo()`?", it can answer you with `typeof(System.Void)`. It has to answer you with *something*, after all.

Comment: @Jon no, i can not compile this, too.

Comment: Well it could answer with `null` instead, but that'd most likely lead to unnecessary special casing in reflection code. And it's important to distinguish the C# language/compiler disallowing something and the CLR itself disallowing it. There is a number of things just forbidden in C# and allowed in the CLR.

Comment: @ordag: It is not legal for *you* to write `typeof(System.Void)` in code. But if you do `Type t = typeof(void)`, then `t` holds the same value it would hold if `Type t = typeof(System.Void)` were legal. It's the *compiler* that doesn't allow you to do this; the CLR wouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: So they could have followed the logic of types more, but left it as a _looks-like-but-is-not_ - type. (And the reason at all is just for getting the `Type` in reflection)

Comment: @ordag: Yes. You might argue it's not "pure" to do so, but I do believe they made the best decision from a practical standpoint.

Comment: I don't think it's just for `Type` reflection. I assume the CLR uses it in its meta-data too for representing the return type of a `void` method. The CLR has to represent that return type somehow after all. And having a pseudo-type for that is a natural choice.

Answer (score 19):

`void`/`System.Void` is different from `int`/`System.Int32`, it's a special *struct* in C#, used for reflection only. See this example:

```
class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Type voidType = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Main").ReturnType;
   }
}
```

There must be some *type* used to describe the return type of `Main` method here, that's why we have `System.Void`.

Comment: If void functions do not return a value and therefore have no return type, why shouldn't the call to MethodInfo.ReturnType return a null instance of Type? To me, Type t = null; means that <t> describes no type at all.

Comment: @CarvoLoco Currently in .NET languages, I believe your suggestion is doable. But here `null` is a magic object, using a specific type makes everything clearer, and explicit.

Answer (score 10):

We have used the following code

```
public Type GetType(object o)
{
    var type = o == null ? typeof(void) : o.GetType();
}
```

so that we can use the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). It's pretty good.
This allows us to do stuff like

```
GetType(o).GetProperties().Select( .....
```

instead of putting guard clauses everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Beyond not returning a value, very little definition is given of `void` (although `void*` gets some attention) in the language spec. This isn't really a language concern - although the CLI may define it further.

Ultimately though: because it has no meaning to do `new void()`

Comment: ah, yes ... `void*` in the `unsafe` c# =/