# C#: Why is there a difference between void and System.Void

Tags: c#, void

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is System.Void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450748/what-is-system-void)
>   [Why not System.Void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408847/why-not-system-void)

I noticed that it is not allowed to use `typeof(System.Void)`. But `typeof(void)` is allowed.
When you use `typeof(System.String)` or `typeof(string)` there is no difference.

Why is this the case?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6408995/44620

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because C# defines aliases to keep the original C flavor.

The .NET Framework uses specific naming conventions: for instance it states that a class name should start with a Capital. Therefore, `String` -- which is not a C# native type but a .NET class defined in the `System` namespace -- is actually called `System.String`, or `String` for short if you have a `using System;` in your file.

C# defines `string` as an alias of `System.String` so that code can look like it does in C and other C-based languages (C++, Java, ...). I think it's more readable. In the same fashion, `int` is the same as `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 1):

`void` is not like `string`. In almost all cases where `void` is used in C#, it is given special treatment by the compiler, for example by not requiring a `return` statement in a `void`-"returning" method, and by not allowing a `return` statement with an expression with a "value" of type `void`. `typeof(void)` is one of the few cases where `void` is really treated as a regular type. And it works both ways: the compiler can assume that any type that is not `void` shouldn't get `void`'s special treatment. Allowing other ways to spell `void` would make interpreting C# more complicated, and there is no reason why you would ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is an alias of class `System.String`.

other list of aliases

- object: System.Object
- string: System.String
- bool: System.Boolean
- byte: System.Byte
- sbyte: System.SByte
- short: System.Int16
- ushort: System.UInt16
- int: System.Int32
- uint: System.UInt32
- long: System.Int64
- ulong: System.UInt64
- float: System.Single
- double: System.Double
- decimal: System.Decimal
- char: System.Char

thanks to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for this.