# What does a void subroutine return?

Tags: c#, .net, subroutine

I was just doing an assessment on pluralsight and was given the following question.

"What does a void subroutine return?"

I was under the impression that a void subroutine did not return anything, but this was not one of the answers provided (Multiple choice question).

Does .Net return a value type in the background or is this question incorrect?

The choices I was given were:
Integer
Boolean
String 
Datetime

Comment: [`System.Void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) is not _nothing_ , it's a `struct` hence a value type.

Comment: void subroutine return no data but the execution control only to calling routine. What choices they gave to select?

Comment: @TimSchmelter of course it's a struct. But his method will not return something to the caller? Correct?

Comment: If you add the multiple choices, we might deduce what direction the question wants you to go.

Comment: Well, perhaps it is difficult to add *nothing* to a list of multiple-choice answers.

Comment: @Christos: i've made my comment an answer.No, you cannot use the return value, the compiler simply forbids it to use `System.Void`.

Comment: The `System.Void` structure allows describe methods in `System.Reflection` uniformly. I suspect also, it simplifies a type inference (implicitly typed variables).

Comment: But a "void subroutine" really does not return anything. There is no return value pushed onto the stack. I suppose the answer could be "According to reflection, it returns "System.Void", but in reality it returns nothing".

Answer (score 6):

[`System.Void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) is not *nothing* , it's a `struct` hence a value type.

However, a method that is a `Sub`(VB.NET) or "returns" `void`(C#) does not really return a value. So you cannot write something like this:

```
System.Void nothing = Foo(); // Foo is a void-method
```

This doesn't compile ("`System.Void` cannot be used from C# -- use typeof(void) to get the void type object"). Related: [Why not System.Void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408847/why-not-system-void)

---

As Jeroen and others have mentioned, actually a `void` method  does really not return anything, so the correct answer was: "It returns nothing".

MSDN mentioned that it's only useful in reflection:

> "The Void structure is used in the System.Reflection namespace, but is
>   rarely useful in a typical application. The Void structure has no
>   members other than the ones all types inherit from the Object class."

If you look at the tooltip on the `void`-keyword you see that it maps to `System.Void`. But again, that doesn't mean that it is returned from the method. It's just a placeholder for a non-existing return value. I guess that `void` also exists due to historical reasons since C# is based on C.

Also worth reading: [Why does void in C mean not void?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254181/why-does-void-in-c-mean-not-void)

Comment: `System.Void` is not nothing, but it is also not what methods declared to return "void" actually return. If that was what they accepted as the correct answer, they've got a question to fix.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: i have edited my answer to emphasize this more.

Answer (score 2):

A method, whose return type is `void`, it does not return anything. You could execute any statements you want inside the method's body. Furthermore this statements can affect anything you want, but *at the end of the day* your method will not return something.